# How to create a multivariate timeseries dataset with tf.data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, lstm, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create an input pipeline for my LSTM model. I am using the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` API to do that. Following the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#time_series_windowing), my current minimal example looks like this:

```
class generator:
    def __init__(self, n=5):
        self.n = n

    def __call__(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            yield (i, 10*i)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator(), 
    output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.uint16), tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)))

window_size = 3
windows = dataset.window(window_size, shift=1)

def sub_to_batch(sub):
    return sub.batch(window_size, drop_remainder=True)

final_dset = windows.flat_map(sub_to_batch)

print(list(final_dset.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

Error message

```
TypeError: tf__sub_to_batch() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This problem only occurs when using more than one feature in the generator (e.g. change the following lines).

```
yield (i)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator(), 
    output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.uint16)))
```

In the version with only 1 feature, the output looks like `shape=(3, 3, 1)`

```
[ [ [0], [1], [2] ],
  [ [1], [2], [3] ],
  [ [2], [3], [4] ]  ]
```

I basically try to achieve a zipping of the individual features so that I get `shape=(3, 3, 2)`:

```
[ [ [0,  0], [1, 10], [2, 20] ],
  [ [1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30] ],
  [ [2, 20], [3, 30], [4, 40] ]  ]
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following; however, I am not sure how efficient it is:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class generator:
    def __init__(self, n=7):
        self.n = n

    def __call__(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            yield (i, 10*i)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator(), 
    output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)))

window_size = 5
windows = dataset.window(window_size, shift=1)

def stack(x, y):
  x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
  y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1)
  result = tf.concat((x, y), axis=1)
  ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
  for w in tf.range(3):
    ta = ta.write(w, result[w: w + 3])
  return ta.stack()

def sub_to_batch(sub1, sub2):
    sub1 = sub1.batch(5, drop_remainder=True)
    sub2 = sub2.batch(5, drop_remainder=True)

    return tf.data.Dataset.zip((sub1, sub2)).map(stack)

final_dset = windows.flat_map(sub_to_batch)
for s in final_dset.take(1):
  print(s)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0  0]
  [ 1 10]
  [ 2 20]]

 [[ 1 10]
  [ 2 20]
  [ 3 30]]

 [[ 2 20]
  [ 3 30]
  [ 4 40]]], shape=(3, 3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

You could also hard-code the indices if you want to and the results will be the same:

```py
def stack(x, y):
  x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
  y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1)
  result = tf.concat((x, y), axis=1)
  return tf.stack([result[0: 3], result[1: 4], result[2: 5]])
```

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply, I got caught up in another task and only recently got to test your suggestion. Although I had to ultimately modify the generator (which has to handle more complex data than in this dummy example), your post definitely got me on the right track. Thank you :)